# PHP web3 ERC20 token function call

Tags: php, laravel, smartcontracts, erc20, web3php

I have a Smart Contract that represent ERC20 token. I already deployed the smart contract on Binance Testnet using HardHat.

I have a deployed Smart Contract address as well.

I have integrated Web3 library in PHP laravel project using following link.

```
https://github.com/web3p/web3.php
```

I can call web3 function to get TOKEN Symbol. It is working fine.

I want to transfer my tokens to some wallet address using 'transfer' function of the Smart contract.

I am using following code.

```
$timeout = 30; // set this time accordingly by default it is 1 sec
$web3 = new Web3(new HttpProvider(new HttpRequestManager('https://data-seed-prebsc-1- s1.binance.org:8545', $timeout)));
$ContractMeta = json_decode(file_get_contents(base_path('public/web3/Token.json')));
$contract = new Contract($web3->provider, $ContractMeta->abi);
$toAccount = 'WALLET_ADDRESS_OF_RECEIVER';
$fromAccount = 'PRIVATE_KEY_OF_SENDER';

$contract->at("DEPLOYED_WALLET_ADDRESS")->send('transfer', $toAccount, 18, [
        'from' => $fromAccount,
        'value' => '1000',
        'gas' => '0x200b20',
        'gasPrice' => '20000000000'
    ], function ($err, $result) use ($contract, $fromAccount, $toAccount) {
        if ($err !== null) {
            throw $err;
        }
        if ($result) {
            echo "\nTransaction has made:) id: " . $result . "\n";
        }
        $transactionId = $result;

        $contract->eth->getTransactionReceipt($transactionId, function ($err, $transaction) use ($fromAccount, $toAccount) {
            if ($err !== null) {
                throw $err;
            }
            if ($transaction) {
                echo "\nTransaction has mind:) block number: " . $transaction->blockNumber . "\nTransaction dump:\n";
                var_dump($transaction);
            }
        });
    });
```

But I am getting following error.

> ```
> {
>   "message": "Wrong type of eth_sendTransaction method argument 0.",
>   "exception": "RuntimeException",
>   "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/web3p/web3.php/src/Methods/EthMethod.php",
>   "line": 125,
>   "trace": [
>     {
>       "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/web3p/web3.php/src/Eth.php",
>       "line": 102,
>       "function": "validate",
>       "class": "Web3\\Methods\\EthMethod",
>       "type": "->"
>     },
>     {
>       "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/web3p/web3.php/src/Contract.php",
>       "line": 572,
>       "function": "__call",
>       "class": "Web3\\Eth",
>       "type": "->"
>     }
>   ]
> }
> ```

Can someone please guide me on solving this?

Here is the Token.json -> ABI

[ABI](https://codeshare.io/vwemOy)

[image: Transfer Function]